# Seeking 1890 County Shapefiles of Scotland

Tags: geospatial, uk, data-mapping

I am struggling to find the county border shapefiles for Scotland that came into effect in 1890. I keep finding "counties before 1890" when googling. So, the file I'm looking for does not include a Glasgow county as Glasgow was still split between Renfrew and Lanark.

Does anyone know where I can find this data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [VisionOfBritain site](https://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/data/) provides two Scottish County files - one pre-1890 and one 1950.

The pre-1890 seems to match your image.

[image]

There is no Glasgow:

[image]